# Working with client OM

Tags: client-object-model

I need to set currentUser to some item field in Client Object Model.
How can I do it?

I always use `new SPFieldUserValue (//,//,//)` in server code, but here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this solution

```
SP.FieldUserValue userValue = new SP.FieldUserValue();
SP.User newUser = ctx.Web.EnsureUser("domain\\username");
ctx.Load(newUser);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
userValue.LookupId = newUser.Id;
listItem["userfield"] = userValue;
listItem.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```